# Moving characters' position

Tags: regex, text-manipulation

I am trying to automate the work of changing the position of characters in text. I think the right regex pattern will do the trick, but I haven't been able to create one.

I have text like this:

```
abcd<ef>efgh (FO)<ef>kl (OF)
xyz<ef>mno
pwr<ef>hijkl (FO)<ef>dfg (OF)
```

I would like it to be like this:

```
abcd<ef>(FO) efgh<ef>(OF) kl
xyz<ef>mno
pwr<ef>(FO) hijkl<ef>(OF) dfg
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using PCRE flavour:

- Find: `(\w+)(\h+)(\(\w+\))`
- Replace: `$3$2$1`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/3m34Im/1)